Extracting daily max temperature data of shapefile area and converting into monthly mean data using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API
I want to correct this code for converting the daily max temperature data into monthly mean temperature data. I have used the ERA5 dataset and want to find data for multiple shapefiles. It shows an error:

Line 60: shapefiles are not defined

I need multiple CSV data from a single code using the loop function
var shapefiles = [
  table,table2
];

var variables = [
  'temperature_2m_max',
  'dewpoint_temperature_2m_max'
];

// Define the time range for the data extraction
var startDate = '1990-01-01';  // Adjust to your desired start date
var endDate = '2024-12-31';    // Adjust to your desired end date

// Load the ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/DAILY_AGGR dataset
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/DAILY_AGGR')
                .filterDate(startDate, endDate);

// Function to process each variable for a given shapefile
function processVariableForShapefile(shapefile, variableName) {
  // Select and clip the variable to the shapefile region
  var variableCollection = dataset.select(variableName).map(function(image) {
    return image.clip(shapefile);
  });
  
    var monthlyData = variableCollection.reduce({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().byMonth(),
    geometry: shapefile.geometry(),
    scale: 1000
  });

  monthlyData = monthlyData.toBands().rename(function(name) {
    return name.split('_')[1]; // Assuming variable name is in format 'variable_name'
  }).reduceToVectors({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
    geometry: shapefile.geometry()
  }).map(function(feature) {
    var date = feature.get('date');
    var year = date.get('year');
    var month = date.get('month');
    return feature.set('Year-Month', ee.Date(year, month).format('YYYY-MM'));
  });
  // Export daily data as a CSV
  var dailyData = variableCollection.map(function(image) {
    var date = image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd');
    image=ee.Image(image).subtract(273.15);
    var stats = image.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: shapefile.geometry(),
      scale: 1000
    });
    return ee.Feature(null, stats).set('date', date);
  });


   // Export monthly data as CSV
  Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: monthlyData,
    folder: '1UPalldistricts_Monthly', // Create a new folder for monthly data
    description: variableName + '_Monthly_Mean_' + shapefile.getInfo().id,
    fileFormat: 'CSV'
  });
}
// Loop over each shapefile and variable
shapefiles.forEach(function(shapefile) {
  variables.forEach(function(variable) {
    processVariableForShapefile(shapefile, variable);
  });
});```

